# Image and value into a GridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a XtraGridview bound to datasource via Linq, when i check some checkbox i need to set an image into a cell and the value they already have.
right now when i check the checkbox i set the image in the cell just fine but eliminate the cell value (the data). 
On CustomDrawCell event i do this

```
private void gridView_GD_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
        {            
                GridView view = sender as GridView;
                string evento1 = Convert.ToString(view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Eve1"));

            if (CVariables.Ficon_estado == 1)
            {
                if (evento1 == "06" || evento1 == "15")
                {
                    if (e.Column.FieldName == "G1")
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        Point pos = CalcPosition(e, imageCollection_16.Images[1]);
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageCollection_16.Images[1], pos);
                        view.Columns["G1"].AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                        view.Columns["G1"].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Far;                        
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                view.Columns["G1"].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
            }
}

 private Point CalcPosition(RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e, Image img)
        {
            Point p = new Point();
            p.X = e.Bounds.Location.X + (e.Bounds.Width - (img.Width * 3)) / 2;
            p.Y = e.Bounds.Location.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - img.Height) / 2;
            return p;
        }
```

[I post an image to illustrate what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gYhm.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell text disappears since you set the **e.Handled** property to true. When this option is set, a default painting mechanism is not invoked. You can still draw a cell text manually by using the **e.Appearance.DrawString** method.

```
e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, e.DisplayText, e.Bounds);
```

Another solution is to show an image by using the [RepositoryItemTextEdit.ContextImage](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemTextEdit_ContextImagetopic.). That is, you can create two **RepositoryItemTextEdits** with different context images and assign them to grid cells conditionally in the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event handler.